# How to resolve Zend_Acl permission conflict for user with multiple roles?

Tags: php, zend-framework, acl, zend-acl, rbac

I'm trying to create an RBAC with Zend_Acl.  The question I have is that I want users to be able to have multiple roles, but I'm not sure how to solve permission conflicts between the various roles?  In cases where there is a both an allow and deny, should the allow always override the deny?  As always, thanks a lot for taking out the time to check out my question.  Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think of it like your home.

- deny | person
- deny | anyone from Russia
- allow | family member
- allow | friend

Let's say you have bad feeling about Russians. Would you think, that you should deny your good friend access to your home just because he is a Russian? No. He has proven some quality that granted him the "friend" status. The allow should override the deny IMO.

*No offense to the Russians :P*

Comment: Hey Tomas, that's exactly what I was thinking, but as I mentioned to Laimoncijus, that would make it difficult for admins to figure out how to deny privileges for roles who inherit an allow permission from a parent role.

Comment: See my answer for that. But if you need to have both, you'd need to have prioritized roles.

Answer (score 1):

you should add role priority to your implementation. If exact resource/privilege pair exists in several roles you will take one on them with highest priority. If none of the roles have exact match - take whatever higher priority role will return.

Another approach is to define user role, like user123

$acl->addRole('user123', array('admin', 'banned'));

I don't know behavior of role with multiple parent roles, so check it out for yourself

Comment: banned shouldn't be a role, I think.

Comment: @Tomáš Fejfar "banned admin" is sort of a joke.

Comment: @Tomáš Fejfar In most cases shouldn't. But consider situation: User violated terms of use of paid service, his account was banned but user must retain access to reports for previous usage.

Comment: True. You're right. But in that case user should be revoked the "paid service" role, not added the "banned", ain't he?

Comment: User will be able to subscribe again then. :-P

Comment: I can invent abstract use cases for abstract service but in real projects i have never used role "banned"

Comment: When in doubt fallback to real life is my favourite quote :) If your friend from my answer stoles something from you (while visiting you), what would you do? I would revoke his "friend" role (cause he not eligible to such a level of trust anymore) rather then add him "thief" role (and keep the trus level high because he is a friend).

Answer (score 1):

Security Best practices indicate when there is a conflict issue a denial.

That being said, from practical experience I build security in the following manner (when it comes to RBAC):

Each user has a set of rights; user rights superseded group rights
Each user can have one or more group rights
Each group has a priority level of application; typically admin is applied where the last applied right
I very rarely apply multiple groups to multiple people; and most people that have rights to apply rights can not do this except for the primary admin (instead I make a new group).
I use Negative (groups with Deny rights) VERY sparingly.
Upon applying group rights to a person I have the system check for conflicts and notify the person applying it.
In addition to the standard RBAC roles I also have a flag grant view others, grant edit others, etc.

In addition use many other mechanisms, such as a sha256 session token, use database tables to temporary check for idle sessions + replay attacks, require the person's ip address stays constant, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Both variants are fine, the question is what you prefer more? Having "deny" priority higher over "allow" would result in system where single "deny" permission would take the rights away, does not matter what others say or vice versa - having "allow" as higher priority would result that single "allow" would grant permission despite many "denys". So questions is - how strict your system should be?

Comment: thx for answering Laimoncijus, for my system, I think it would make more sense to have the "allow" property have a higher priority, but I was wondering if this could cause issues, especially when trying to set a deny permission for a specific role in cases where it inherits an "allow" property from a parent role.  It may make it more difficult for admins to be able to know how to actually set permissions to "deny".

Comment: @blacktie24 I guess in this case deny permission does not really make sense then - because if there is a single allow at any place, deny then would be always ignored... so I guess you need deny at higher prio over allow - so admins could easy add deny it would restrict user directly